# 404 Page Not Found. The page you requested was not found. Codeigniter 3.0.6

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

i have problem with CodeIgniter3: 404 Page Not Found

File: application/controllers/Welcome.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {   
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('Welcome_Page');
    }
    public function tutorial()
    {
        $this->load->view('Tutorial_Page');
    }
    public function manual()
    {
        $this->load->view('Manual_Page');
    }
    public function forum()
    {
        $this->load->view('Forum_Page');
    }
    public function register()
    {
        $this->load->view('Register_Page');
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('Login_Page');
    }
}
```

File: application/config/autoload/php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

File: application/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

File: application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.domain.tld';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

File: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Page loads Welcome_Page, but not other pages.

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

In folder views, exist pages: Forum_Page.php, Login_Page.php, Manual_Page.php, Register_Page.php, Tutorial_Page.php and Welcome_Page.php

Thank you so much for understanding!

Comment: show your URL trying to access. And there should be an trailing slash in `base_url`

Comment: I tried: $config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.domain.tld/'; ... not working.

Comment: Try with change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`.

Comment: I don't get another result :(

Comment: @AurelBercea show us your live site address

Comment: My site in developement: http://sgd.poartastelara.ro/

Comment: `http://sgd.poartastelara.ro/welcome/tutorial` for example is working as well.

Comment: WOW! Thank you! But is possible without /welcome/ ?

Comment: Could have been easily answered by reading this =>  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I see now. Your problem is in routing. You are meant to reach pages as

```
http://sub.domain.tld/welcome/tutorial
http://sub.domain.tld/welcome/manual
...
```

but you created view HTML to get

```
http://sub.domain.tld/tutorial
http://sub.domain.tld/manual
...
```

In `APPPATH.'config/routes.php'` file, under reserved routes you have to reroute your calls in way of:

```
$config[(:any)] = 'welcome/$1'
```

Two things are here you need to pay attention:

1. Placeholder `(:any)` would take place for `$1`,
2. Your route that contains `(:any)` parameter have to be at the end of file because

   > Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

More of that [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html). Check that whole page and other pages in docs as well.

Comment: #SOreadytohelp Feel free [to accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (and upvote) as it fixed your problem to help others easier find solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Replace your .htaccess code with the following code: YOURPROJECTNAME is your base folder. e.g. if you are on local server and your project is called myproblem, then replace 'YOURPROJECTNAME' with 'myproblem'

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* YOURPROJECTNAME/index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

ensure that the .htaccess is at the root of your app also.

Comment: I displays error: 500
Internal Server Error

An internal server error has occured.

Comment: Is your application running on a local server?

Comment: No... running on a shared server

Comment: Replace the code with (It works for me when I run on a public domain): <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>